# What does it mean to double license?

Tags: licensing

What does it mean to double license code? I can't just put both licenses in the source files. That would mean that I mandate users to follow the rules of both of them, but the licenses will probably be contradictory (otherwise there'd be no reason to double license).

I guess this is something like in cryptographic chaining, `cipher  = crypt_2(crypt_1(clear))` (generally) means, that `cipher` is neither the output of `crypt_2` on `clear` nor the output of `crypt_1` on `clear`. It's the output of the composition.

Likewise, in double-licensing, in reality my code has *one* license, it's just that this new license says *please follow all of the rules of license1, or all of the rules of license2, and you are hereby granted the right to redistribute this application under this "double" license, license1 or license2, or any license under which license1 or license2 allow you to redistribute this software, in which case you shall replace the relevant licensing information in this application with that of the new license*.

(Does this mean that before someone may use the app under license1, he has to perform the operation of redistributing to self? How would he document the fact that he did that operation?)

Am I correct. What LICENSE file and what text to put in the source files would I need if I wanted to double license on, for the sake of example, Apachev2 and GPLv3 ?

Comment: Aha! Ruby has an explicit master license: http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/LICENSE.txt

Comment: Agreement just takes twice as much space as a `float` license

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it.

I think it is like this:

by distributing his program's source code with a `LICENSE` file, the developer effectively makes a promise that he will grant any interested party a license to his program.

So when somebody starts downloading the source code, it is understood that at that moment the developer grants him a license to his program.

The developer may "release the software under a double license", which actually means that his promise is to grant the interested party a license she chooses, to his program.

This interpretation eliminates the factitious problem I had with performing a

```
license['my-program-v1.0'] := GPLv3
license['my-program-v1.0'] := SomeOtherLicense
```

at the same time, in parallel and keeping both values assigned to `license['my-program-v1.0']` intact.

Answer (score 6):

The double license allows users to choose which license to use.

Say, if you release your software under a GPL and a BSD license, I can choose to use and extend your software under any of those licenses.

You can also choose to triple or multiple license your project, and then your users can pick any license.

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption about double licensing is correct. If you include two license's people are simply bound to follow whichever license fits their needs the best.

> Example, License 1:
>   You may not
>   redistribute,
>   You may use for personal or corporate
>   use.
>
> License 2:
>   You may redistribute,
>   You
>   may not modify the code.

I can now pick from either of the two, but can't mash-up things from both.

This also raises the question, do you **really** need to double license? Why not forge your own license using the rules most desirable to you from the two combined.

Distributing with two licenses can also create forks in the code, since the user is restricted to follow one license agreement they may no longer be able to distribute under both agreements that you specified. Example, if two teams of developers each work on a different license there is a chance that they cannot combine their codes because doing such would violate a rule from one or both.

Comment: You can include both, but as I stated it could make recombining the code impossible in some instances.

Comment: IANAL, but including them should suffice. The recipient can choose to agree to either license in full. I might license a song I wrote to different people without having to write some "master license" that includes all of them.

Comment: But does including the licenses suffice or do I have to make a composite license pointing at that two? Then the new developments would simply be licensed under the composite-license.

Comment: I could have many git repositories with same contents each under a different license :)))

Comment: I downvoted this, because I think it's horrible idea to customize licenses unless it's really required. Dual licensing is much better. It's so much better to have code under some well known license ("MIT"/"BSD"/"GPL"/"Apache"/...). With that, you don't have to read that text every time, you just know what it states after reading it once.

Answer (score -2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-licensing